# MySQL5.6 on Mac OS X 10.6.8 problems when granting permissions to root

Tags: mysql, mac-os-x, mysql-5.6

I'm having serious problems with a MySQL 5.6 instance on a Mac Server.

We had to upgrade MySQL to a newer version, but it turned to be a bad idea, as we lost control to it. We had a backup of the /data directory and the my.cnf file as well. However, when setting an init_file to restore the previous password and its permissions. So we created a text file with this content:

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET Password=PASSWORD('myOriginalPassword') WHERE User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

We have double checked the init_file permissions (we even gave it a chmod 777, to make sure it worked), but something is not working. When we run `mysqld_safe --init_file=/usr/local/mysql/bin/init_file` it tries to start the server, but then it shuts itself down. The log is as follows:

```
130308 13:23:52 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /usr/local/mysql/data
2013-03-08 13:23:53 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /usr/local/mysql/data/ is case insensitive
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: CPU does not support crc32 instructions
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: 1.2.10 started; log sequence number 19440939
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [ERROR] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: unknown option '--skip-locking'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [ERROR] Aborting

2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Binlog end
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INSERTED'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
2013-03-08 13:23:53 18979 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 19440949
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
2013-03-08 13:23:54 18979 [Note] /usr/local/mysql/bin/mysqld: Shutdown complete

130308 13:23:54 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /usr/local/mysql/data/server.myServerName.com.pid ended
```

The problem may definitely come from the [Error] lines, but as we haven't used the --skip-locking, it's just confusing. If we try to log into mysql using `mysql -r -p` and set the password we used, it can't connect to the server, as it is not started. Any ideas where this problem may come from?

Answer (score 1):

I just noticed you have [**`lower_case_table_names`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) defaulted to 2.

According to the MySQL Documentation on [**`lower_case_table_names`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names)

> You should not set this variable to 0 if you are running MySQL on a system that has case-insensitive file names (such as Windows or Mac OS X). If you set this variable to 0 on such a system and access MyISAM tablenames using different lettercases, index corruption may result. On Windows the default value is 1. On Mac OS X, the default value is 2.
>
> If you are using InnoDB tables, you should set this variable to 1 on all platforms to force names to be converted to lowercase.

Since you do not set anything, MySQL has set [**`lower_case_table_names`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) to 2, which is very bad for InnoDB. This at least explains why InnoDB won't start up.

You will have set [**`lower_case_table_names`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_lower_case_table_names) to 1 and try again.

Give it a Try !!!

Answer (score 0):

As per MySQL 5.6,
Instead of using `skip-locking` in your my.cnf configuration file, change the parameter with `skip-external-locking`. then restart your MySQL Service.